# laravel - How to list all Event of an calendar if I have permission

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, api, calendar

I have an web application use Google Calendar API. When someone access to my Web App, they will give me an permissions to access their calendar. For example: Mr B access to my Web App can access his calendar.

**How can I access to B's Calendar if he give me permissions to access his calendar ?**

Edit:

If I'm Mr A and I access to my Web App, I can do everything with Google Calendar  like Create an event, Invite a atendees, ... .

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));
    $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);
    $this->client = $client;    }

public function oauth()
{
    session_start();
    $rurl = action('EventController@oauth');
    $this->client->setRedirectUri($rurl);
    if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
        $filtered_url = filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        return redirect($filtered_url);
    } else {
        $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $this->client->getAccessToken();
        return redirect()->route('event.index');
    }
}
```

Function create an event.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    session_start();
    $startDateTime = $request->start_date;
    $endDateTime = $request->end_date;
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $this->client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);
        $calendarId = 'primary';
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event([
            'summary' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'start' => ['dateTime' => $startDateTime],
            'end' => ['dateTime' => $endDateTime],
            'reminders' => ['useDefault' => true],
            'attendees' => [
                ['email' => $request->invite],
            ],
            ]);
        $results = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);

        if (!$results) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Something went wrong']);
        }
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Event Created']);
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('oauthCallback');
    }
}
```

**But If Mr B access to my Web App. How can I controll B's Calendar ?**

Please Help,

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @J.Robinson No, I'm not. I just know how to do that. I mean if I'm Mr A and I access to my Web App, I can do everything with Google Calendar API. I can do that. But if Mr B access to my Web App, I don't know how to controll B's Calendar. I will update code right now.